# How to fix error failed to initialize because catalogname is Missing in c#.net

Tags: c#, initialization, runtime-error, windows

I have a windows app in c#.net ant I was working with it .suddenly I runned the application and I encountered with error  failed  to initialize because catalogname is Missing in line below

```
((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.performanceCounter1)).EndInit();
```

How can I fix this error

code

```
 SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(DBsetting.Connstring);
                SqlDataAdapter sqlda = new SqlDataAdapter("SelectUserswith", sqlconn);
                sqlda.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                sqlda.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@n", textBox1.Text.Trim());
                dt.Clear();
                sqlda.Fill(dt);
                if (dt.Rows!=null && dt.Rows.Count > 0 && dt.Rows[0]["username"] != null && dt.Rows[0]["Depassword"].ToString() == textBox2.Text.Trim())
                {
                    this.Hide();
                    MenuFrm f1 = new MenuFrm();     
                    f1.un = dt.Rows[0]["name"].ToString();
                    f1.uID = dt.Rows[0]["ID"].ToString();
                    f1.username = dt.Rows[0]["username"].ToString();
                    f1.Show();
                }
               else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("نام کاربری یا رمز عبور شما اشتباه میباشد");
                }
```

error message :

```
   at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter.InitializeImpl()
   at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter.EndInit()
   at HozoorGhiyabSoftware.MenuFrm.InitializeComponent() in C:\Users\JAVAD\Desktop\HozoorGhiyabSoftwareForWin7WithEzafkari\HozoorGhiyabSoftware\MenuFrm.Designer.cs:line 1291
   at HozoorGhiyabSoftware.MenuFrm..ctor() in C:\Users\JAVAD\Desktop\HozoorGhiyabSoftwareForWin7WithEzafkari\HozoorGhiyabSoftware\MenuFrm.cs:line 28
   at HozoorGhiyabSoftware.Program.Main() in C:\Users\JAVAD\Desktop\HozoorGhiyabSoftwareForWin7WithEzafkari\HozoorGhiyabSoftware\Program.cs:line 19
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: Please share the code and the error message in detail.

Comment: Your code does not include the line you think is causing the error. So which line of code actually is throwing the error when you debug? The question is not clear. Also that is a stacktrace not errormessage, add the exact error message to the question.

Comment: I assume your database connection details are in DBsetting.Connstring, debug its values when you create the sql connection object to check if the catalog name is specified

Comment: while creating an object of Menufrm this error ocured    MenuFrm f1 = new MenuFrm();